# Sliding divs down into a visible area using CSS3 animate or jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm attempting to create a graph, where the bars slide down upon a link click.  I've tried using jQuery, but nothing happens.  My `#click_to_animate` object is a standard link.  From my understanding, the objects should begin outside of a box which doesn't show `overflow`, and then upon clicking on the link, the objects should recess downward until `margin-top` is set at 0.

HTML

```
<div class="graph-inner">
    <div class="inner-title">
        <h3 style="color:#666">0</h3><h4>n=28</h4>
    </div><!--/.inner-title-->
    <div class="graph-charts">
        <div class="bars">
            <div class="gb"><span class="graph-number"><h3>5</h3><h4>30</h4></span></div>
            <div class="bb"><span class="graph-number"><h3>6</h3><h4>56</h4></span></div>
            <div class="ob"><span class="graph-number"><h3>7</h3><h4>114</h4></span></div>
       </div><!--/.bars-->
    </div><!--/.graph-charts--> 
</div><!--/.graph-inner-->
```

jQuery

```
$('#click_to_animate').click(function() {
    $('.gb').animate({
        marginTop:'0'
    }, 200);
})//end click
```

CSS

```
.graph-charts {
    border-top:3px solid #666;
    width:600px;
    position:absolute;
    left:95px;
    top:173px;
    overflow:none;
    }    
.inner-title {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:160px;
    top: 110px;
    }
.bars {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    }
.gb {
    background-color: #009966;
    height: 295px;
    width:75px;
    position:absolute;
    left:190px;
    margin-top:-295px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:.3em;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:.3em;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:.3em;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:.3em;
    border-bottom-right-radius:.3em;
    border-bottom-left-radius:.3em;
    }
.bb {
    background-color: #3366cc;
    height: 100px;
    width:75px;
    position:absolute;
    left:310px;
    margin-top:-295px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:.3em;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:.3em;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:.3em;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:.3em;
    border-bottom-right-radius:.3em;
    border-bottom-left-radius:.3em;
    }
.ob {
    background-color: #cc6600;
    height: 100px;
    width:75px;
    position:absolute;
    left:430px;
    margin-top:-295px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:.3em;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:.3em;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:.3em;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:.3em;
    border-bottom-right-radius:.3em;
    border-bottom-left-radius:.3em;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your `.graph-charts` css class. Give it a `height` and set `overflow` to `hidden` not `none` (which is invalid).

```
.graph-charts {
    border-top:3px solid #666;
    width:600px;
    height: 500px;
    position:absolute;
    left:95px;
    top:173px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyWLR/)

Comment: Not sure what's going on, then. I just copied the code you posted and added a link to start the animation.